# Traverse $_POST Array to show field Names

Tags: php, http-post

Is there a way to traverse an array such as $_POST to see the field names and not just the values.  To see the values I do something like this.

```
foreach ($_POST as $value){
echo $value;
}
```

This will show me the values - but I would like to also display the names in that array.  If my $_POST value was something like $_POST['something'] and it stored 55;  I want to output "something".

I have a few select fields that I need this for.

Comment: Perfect!  I knew there had to be something other than $value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value )
{
  echo "$key : $value <br>";
}
```

you can also use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) if you just want an array of the keys to iterate over.

You can also use [`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) if you want to use a callback to iterate:

```
function test_walk( &$value, $key )
{
  ...do stuff...
}

array_walk( $arr, 'test_walk' );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo $key; // Field name
}
```

Or use [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to fetch all the keys from an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo $key.': '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the keys:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
{
    echo $key;
}
```

Or...

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
}
```

If you want both keys and values:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key, ': ', $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For just the keys:

> $array = array_keys($_POST);

Output them with:

> var_dump($array);

-or-

> print_r($array);